# Why can I import from a package which is not part of my dependencies?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, turtlesim, packages, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a ROS package, `my_package`, with dependencies `rospy` and `geometry_msgs`. Then I created a Python script, `my_script.py`, (which is located under `src`) for `my_package`.

To my surprise, in `my_script.py`, I can import from the package `turtlesim`, like `from turtlesim.msg import Pose`, without getting errors. So, `turtlesim` seems to be part of my dependencies. Why is that?

If execute the following command on the terminal `rospack depends my_package`, the output is the following:

```
cpp_common
rostime
roscpp_traits
roscpp_serialization
catkin
genmsg
genpy
message_runtime
std_msgs
geometry_msgs
gencpp
geneus
gennodejs
genlisp
message_generation
rosbuild
rosconsole
rosgraph_msgs
xmlrpcpp
roscpp
rosgraph
ros_environment
rospack
roslib
rospy
```

which does not include `turtlesim`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287858/why-can-i-import-from-a-package-which-is-not-part-of-my-dependencies?/) by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 372 on 2018-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> To my surprise, in `my_script.py`, I can import from the package `turtlesim`, like `from turtlesim.msg import Pose`, without getting errors. So, `turtlesim` seems to be part of my dependencies. Why is that?

`turtlesim` is not part of your dependencies, as it isn't in the list that `rospack depends` shows, is not listed in your `package.xml` nor your `CMakeLists.txt`. Questions #q217475 and #q215059 can perhaps provide some more insight into how package dependencies are encoded and resolved by the various pieces of infrastructure.

As to why you can import the `turtlesim` Python *module*, that is because it is on the `PYTHONPATH` as soon as you `source` the appropriate `setup.(ba|z)sh`. If it's installed from a `deb`, you can find all ROS packages that provide Python modules under `/opt/ros/$distro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. As Python does not need any linking or compilation, just placing a module on its search path is enough to be able to `import` it.

---

Edit:

> When I said " seems to be part of my dependencies" I didn't mean that it's part of my dependencies, in fact, I said, "seems to".

And I just made it explicit that it isn't.

> Do you ever assume that a package is under `/opt/ros/$distro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` or do you always prefer to specify the dependency in the `package.xml` file, even if *you* have the same package under `/opt/ros/$distro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`?

Never assume anything. You cannot assume anything about the state of the system that your package / script(s) will be run on: your next user might have a full install of "all" ROS pkgs, or have a very barren installation with just `ros_comm` and some dependencies. Always make your dependencies explicit so that your users know what they should provide (but then use `rosdep` to take care of that for you, #q252478).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-08**:
Note that the fact that you `import`ed `turtlesim` in one of your scripts now *does* make it a runtime dependency of `my_package`, but one which is implicit, as you've not expressed that dependency in any of the files that normally list those (ie: `package.xml`).

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2018-04-08**:
When I said " seems to be part of my dependencies" I didn't mean that it's part of my dependencies, in fact, I said, "seems to".

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2018-04-08**:
Do you ever assume that a package is under `/opt/ros/$distro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` or do you always prefer to specify the dependency in the `package.xml` file, even if *you* have the same package under `/opt/ros/$distro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`?